# $y=\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2} $how to transform this into $x$

Tags: integration

$y=\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}$ how to transform this into $x$?

I am trying to revers the order of integration of a double integral where the upper bound with respect to $y$ is $y=\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}$ but i cannot figure out how to deal with this?

Graphing the $y$ I could find out it if a semi-circle above the $X$-axis centred at $(2,0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\implies y^2=4-(x-2)^2\iff(x-2)^2=4-y^2\implies x-2=\pm\sqrt{4-y^2}$$